# How do I safely run a graphical application as a normal user while root?

Tags: sudo, gksu

We often talk about using `gksu`, `sudo -i` and `pkexec` to run things as root while a normal user but I'm facing the opposite problem today. The script I'm using is running as root. I need it to start a graphical application on a set user's desktop as that user.

I don't want to bomb `.Xauthority` or any of that, so what's the safest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

`sudo -i` should work in reverse too but you need to state which user you want to run as:

```
DISPLAY=:0 sudo -i -u oli zenity --info --text "Oh hai!"
```

Comment: If you're root, you don't need `sudo`, because you have all the rights to use `su` to any user. Moreover, `sudoers` may forbid root to run `sudo`.